# Applying symbology to group of layer using ArcPy in ArcGis 10.1?

Tags: arcpy, symbology

I am creating a python script and one of the things i need to do is apply symbology from layer to a group of shapefile in my mxd . But when i specified the folder of symbology layer, symbology deosn't working, without any error message.

```
import arcpy.mapping  
mxd=arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
def importer ():
    # Set outWorkspace
    outWorkspace = r'c:\Users\HAIDRA\Documents\Desktop\essai'
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("current")
    style = askdirectory ()
    styl_path.set(style)
    # set the workspace
    arcpy.env.workspace = style 
    list = arcpy.ListFiles("*")
    print list
    # Execute MakeFeatureLayer for each input shapefile
    for li in list:
        #make a layer from a feature
        styllist = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management (li, li +"_lyr")
        for styl in styllist:
            print styl
    # Script arguments
    styllist = styl_layers
    styl_layers = arcpy.GetParameterAsText()
    layer = Layers_to_Symbolize
    Layers_to_Symbolize = arcpy.GetParameterAsText()
    # Process: Apply Symbology From Layer
    for UpdateLayer in Layers_to_Symbolize:
            arcpy.AddMessage("Updating: " + UpdateLayer)
            arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(UpdateLayer,styl_layer)
    Output_Symbology = styl_layer
    arcpy.RefreshTOC()
    del mxd
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing

```
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

before

```
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
```